# Can XSLT generate locally invalid HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
  ...
  <cb n="1" />
  ...
  <cb n="2" />
  ...
  <cb n="" />
  ...
</text>
```

Each column-inated section in the XML document starts with a `<cb n="1" />` tag and ends with a `<cb n="" />` tag, with a one or more `<cb n="2" />`, `<cb n="3" />` etc. tags in between them. The `<cb>` tags are all immediate children of `<text>`. I want to generate HTML where each `<cb n="1" />...<cb n="" />` block is transformed into `<div>...</div>`, and each `<cb n="x" />...<cb n="x+1" />` block is transformed into `<div class="column">...</div>`. For example, the output of the XML above would be

```
<html>
  <body>
    ...
    <div>
      <div class="column">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

My XSLT stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="text">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this is the part that fails -->
  <xsl:template match="cb[@n='1']">
    <div>
      <div class="column">
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cb[@n='']">
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cb">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this doesn't work because the stylesheet itself isn't valid XML. Is this transformation possible in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible, but not as you're approaching the problem at the tag level.  Do not try to control start and end tags separately; rather, control them together as part of an *element*.  Post a [mcve] if you need further details to understand that explanation.

Comment: @kjhughes What additional information do you need for a MCVE? Do you want me to include the full stylesheet?

Comment: MCVE implies a minimal, *complete*, input XML document, minimal XSLT code that actually runs, actual XML output, and desired XML output.

Comment: @kjhughes See my edit, but note that my question is not why my solution failed but how to achieve this particular transformation.

Comment: Please explain the required logic in words. The example is ambiguous. The expected result could be achieved very simply by creating a  `div` for each `cb[@n>0]`.

Comment: I think I see where you're going, but I hesitate to edit it into the question because I am making substantial inferences.  Please correct me where I am wrong: (1) The `<cb>` elements represent breaks between columns of text; (2) they will appear in the input only as children of the root `<text>` element; (3) each `<cb>` will have an `n` attribute with a distinct value; (4) you want to transform everything before the first `<cb>` or after the last `<cb>` as itself;

Comment: ... (5) you want to transform everything from the first `<cb>` to the last as the body of a `<div>`; (6) within that containing div, you want to transform everything between each pair of consecutive `<cb>` elements as the content of a `<div class="column">`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited my question to clarify these points, let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: This looks like a grouping question. Could you replace the `...` parts with a more realistic example, and - if there can be more than one group (presumably ending with `<cb n=""/>` ?) - show at least two of them in your input, as well as in the expected output?

Comment: Also state if you can use XSLT 2.0, where grouping is much easier.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am restricted to XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that when generating HTML or XML output, XSL generates output elements whole; isolated start or end tags cannot be emitted into the output (in part because they are not accepted in the input).  It follows that every node in the output document comes from the transformation of a specific node in the input document, so part of your job as a transformation author is to choose which input nodes to transform into the desired output nodes.

In particular, the only good candidates for the the source node for the `<div>` containing the output column group are the `<text>` element and one of the `<cb>` elements.  If you choose the latter, then you'll need to choose one with a distinguishing characteristic, such as being the first or last, or having a specific attribute value.

Furthermore, whichever node's transform provides the containing `<div>` must *also* be responsible for the column-group contents, because there's no way for a template to add content to an output node produced by a different template, or even a different instantiation of the same template.  If you let the template for the `<text>` element transform those too, then you'll have to do extra work to avoid unwanted output.

Here's one way you could put that together:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <!-- identity transform for nodes not otherwise matched with a template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='/text'>
    <html>
      <body>
        <!-- transform child nodes up to and including the first <cb>, if any -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(preceding::cb)]" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for most <cb> elements: -->
  <xsl:template match="cb">
    <xsl:variable name="column" select="preceding-sibling::cb[1]/@n" />
    <div class="column">
      <!-- contents come from transforming nodes between the previous <cb>
           and this one -->
      <xsl:apply-templates
          select="preceding-sibling::node()[preceding-sibling::cb[@n = $column]]" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for <cb> elements that are their parent's first child;
       produces the column-group div, its contents, and the nodes following -->
  <xsl:template match="cb[1]">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::cb" />
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates
        select="../cb[position() = last()]/following-sibling::node()" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That doesn't make use of (and therefore does not depend on) the specific values of the input `n` attributes; it relies only on them being distinct.  Moreover, because it creates the column group's containing `<div>` by transforming the first `<cb>`, it will omit that altogether of there aren't any `<cb>` elements.  Overall, note the use of the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axes to select the nodes between other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not entirely clear. If I am guessing correctly, you want to take an input like:

**XML**

```
<text>
    <cb n="1">a</cb>
    <cb n="2">b</cb>
    <cb n="2">c</cb>
    <cb n=""></cb>
    <cb n="4">d</cb>
    <cb n="5">e</cb>
    <cb n=""></cb>
    <cb n="6">f</cb>
    <cb n="7">g</cb>
    <cb n="8">h</cb>
    <cb n="9">i</cb>
    <cb n="">j</cb>
</text>
```

and create a `div` wrapper for each group of consecutive `cb` elements ending with `<cb n=""/>`. This is very easy to do in XSLT 2.0, but a little more tricky in XSLT 1.0:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="cb-by-end" match="cb[not(@n='')]" use="generate-id(following-sibling::cb[@n=''][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cb[@n='']" mode="group"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cb" mode="group">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('cb-by-end', generate-id())"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cb">
    <div class="column">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="column">a</div>
            <div class="column">b</div>
            <div class="column">c</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="column">d</div>
            <div class="column">e</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="column">f</div>
            <div class="column">g</div>
            <div class="column">h</div>
            <div class="column">i</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```